# How to guard TypeScript code for derived conditions (strict mode)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

TypeScript (in strict mode) supports protecting code by mean of previous conditions used as guards, so the following error:

```js
export const myFun1 = (data: { a?: string; b?: string }) => {
    const obj = { a: 1, b: 2 };
    return obj[data.a]; // Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type
}
```

Can be avoided easily with a kind of conditional guard (`if (!data.a) return;`) as follows:

```js
export const myFun1 = (data: { a?: string; b?: string }) => {
    if (!data.a) return;
    const obj = { a: 1, b: 2 };
    return obj[data.a]; // No error
}
```

In the same way, we would have an error with `b` property that could be avoided, too:

```js
export const myFun1 = (data: { a?: string; b?: string }) => {
    if (!data.a || !data.b) return;
    const obj = { a: 1, b: 2 };
    return obj[data.a] + obj[data.b]; // No error
}
```

This code is 100% valid. No errors at all. But now I want to group checks in a boolean so that it is checked for the `return`. Surprisingly, the following does not work as I expected and TypeScript keeps throwing a type error:

```js
export const myFun1 = (data: { a?: string; b?: string }) => {
    const both = data.a && data.b;
    if (!both) return;
    const obj = { a: 1, b: 2 };
    return obj[data.a] + obj[data.b]; // Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type
}
```

What am I missing? What is the reason behind this weird behavior?

I was expecting TypeScript not to complain when both checks are grouped into an intermediate boolean.

Comment: Please avoid using images, include the code snippet instead so that we can copy the code in our IDEs and only see the error that you are trying to fix

Comment: `if (!(data.a && data.b)) return;` works as expected. I think this a good question.

Comment: @wonderflame ey! You're totally right. Much better with code snippets. Good suggestion. Done :-)

Comment: In your last example `both` is inferred as `srring | undefined`, which is curious, but even changing it to `const both = data.a !== undefined && data.b !== undefined;`, which correctly returns `boolean` also doesn't work as a typeguard.

Comment: Also, there is no relation between obj and data's properties. Is it okay to defined obj as Record<string, number>?

Comment: @Cuzy it is ok that `both` is inferred as `string | undefined` because it is based on a `&&` chain of `string | undefined` elements, so `both` value is the last non-falsy item of the chain.

Comment: @wonderflame using `Record<string, number>` is enough for this to illustrate the situation. This way it is indexable by any string. Of course it is possible `obj[data.a]` is undefined, but it is not a problem. The return type of the function will be `number | undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript is not that smart to consider `both` as a type-guard. For the compiler `both` is independent of the `data`. The simplest way would be to use    the following code directly:

```
const func = (data: {a?: string; b?: string}) => {
   if (!(data.a && data.b)) return;
   // do stuff
}
```

Otherwise, you can use [asserting function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions):

```
function isRequiredData(data: Data): asserts data is Required<Data> {
  if (!data.a || !data.b) {
    throw new Error('data has missing properties');
  }
}

const func = (data: Data) => {
  isRequiredData(data);

  // data.a and data.b here are not optional
}
```

This still won't fix the all errors, since `obj` has no type annotation and the compiler gets the type from the value, which is `{a: string; b: string}`.
As the easiest solution we can type the `obj` as a `Record<string, number>` and for more security in run time check whether `data.a` and `data.b` are in the `obj`:

```
const func = (data: Data) => {
  isRequiredData(data);

  const obj: Record<string, number> = { a: 1, b: 2 };

  if (data.a in obj && data.b in obj) {
    return obj[data.a] + obj[data.b];
  }

  return -1;
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UDeAoKU4H4BcUAzsAE4CWAdgOYDcWUARgcWVXRgL70YBmArpQDGwcgHtKUckQBKEAI79ypCABN4iABSqEcQhrgBKQnCJEIpYESg7EU63MXK1AHgMA+dA3K8omgIS2cAB0SAA+YVCBusGMhl7Y2MAAFqRiAO5QlBCZAKKkaaSaAORBUMmmUAC20kTsUGBpkJbkEETFhvTYnFwYGEISJFACwih+Qfq68ciemNjSjkoq6rraUzzYA5RDYowAVoRyA6SqLiQUNAA0WfxVjBaeqGg4hACM14yEAExQ3H3zvjWiFCUkkuz2UAAZJCbDFGKCoOD4nNEipgPxSGD9gBtIKhAC6UAA1IicXjGPiur9-lA0RjJABaV70P5AA)

As an alternative, you can use custom [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) instead of the assertion function if you don't need to throw an error:

```
function isRequiredData(data: Data): data is Required<Data> {
  return !!data.a && !!data.b;
}

const func = (data: Data) => {
  if (!isRequiredData(data)) return;

  const obj: Record<string, number> = { a: 1, b: 2 };

  if (data.a in obj && data.b in obj) {
    return obj[data.a] + obj[data.b];
  }

  return -1;
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UDeAoKU4H4BcUAzsAE4CWAdgOYDcWUARgcWVXRgL70YBmArpQDGwcgHtKUckQBKEAI79ypCABN4iABSqEcQhrgBKQjsRSiUOYuVqAPAYB86BiuD9SkgISfTcAHRIAGSBUN6+foz0nBgYQhIkUALCKFDauvq6hihOmNjkvKme0lZKKuq6aYiGWa7ulDzYcZQJYowAVoRycaSqtiQUNAA0UJT8ALaMEKROqGg4hACMw4yEAExQ3DF5BZX+SFRQrW1QwVDhjFKSR1m52FC1HoftANrhcAC6UADUT22vuhF3vRsNEXBA3I8ALQLKL0IA)